# How do I use a loop to find the min and max values of an array in Assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, max, mips, qtspim

I'm trying to find and print the minimum and maximum values of an array in Assembly. My main issue right now is incrementing the value of the index for the array. I keep getting syntax errors when I load my file into QTSpim. I'm sure there are many more issues but I'll get to those later.

My question is why can't I increment the array to the next value? What is the syntax error?

Here's my code:

```
        .data

    array:      .word   5, 7, 12, 3, 4, 9, 6, 11, 2, 10
    array_size: .word   10
    array_min:  .asciiz "\nMin: " 
    array_max:  .asciiz "\nMax: "



    .text
    .globl main

main:   

    la $a1, array       # loading memory address of array

    addi $t0, $zero, 0  # setting index incrementer to 0
    lw $s1, 0($a1)      # setting $s1 to the smallest index of the array
    lw $s2, 0($a1)      # setting $s2 to the smallest index of the array

while:

    beq $t0, 10, exit   # branch to exit if $t0 is 10
    addi $t1, $t1, 4    # too add the next four bytes for the array index

    blt array($t1), $s1, minimum    # branch to minimum if $array[$t1] < $s1 
    blt array($t1), $s2, maximum    # branch to maximum if $array[$t1] < $s2

    minimum:
        lw $s1, array($t1)
        j while
    maximum:
        lw $s2, array($t1)
        j while



    addi $t0, $t0, 1    # increment $t0 by 1

    j while             # jump to the beginning of the while loop

exit:   

    li $v0, 4           # prints the array_min string
    la $a0, array_min
    syscall

    li $v0, 1           # prints the smallest integer
    move $a0, $s1
    syscall

    li $v0, 4           # prints the array_max string
    la $a0, array_max
    syscall

    li $v0, 1           # prints the largest integer
    move $a0, $s2
    syscall


    li $v0, 10          # terminates program
    syscall
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message you are getting?  Include that in your question.

Comment: Sorry, it says: spim: (parser) syntax error on line 26 of file:* blt array($t1, $s1, minimum # branch to minimum if $array[$t1] < $s1

Comment: `blt` can't take a memory operand; only load/store can do that.  MIPS is a load/store RISC machine, not a CISC.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's working MIPS code that does this.

```
.data

array:      .word   5, 7, 12, 3, 4, 9, 6, 11, 2, 10
array_size: .word   10
array_min:  .asciiz "\nMin: " 
array_max:  .asciiz "\nMax: "

.text

main:   
    la $a0, array
    lw $a1, array_size
    lw $t2, ($a0) # max
    lw $t3, ($a0) # min
    loop_array:
        beq $a1, $zero, print_and_exit
        lw $t0, ($a0)
        bge $t0, $t3, not_min # if (current_element >= current_min) {don't modify min} 
        move $t3, $t0
        not_min:
        ble $t0, $t2, not_max # if (current_element <= current_max) {don't modify max}
        move $t2, $t0
        not_max:
        addi $a1, $a1, -1
        addi $a0, $a0, 4
        j loop_array

    print_and_exit:
    # print maximum
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, array_max
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t2
    syscall 

    # print minimum
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, array_min
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t3
    syscall 

    # exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```